# Query to get rows with a UNIX Timestamp of today

Tags: php, sql, date, unix-timestamp

In my DB I have UNIX Timestamps as due dates for jobs that need to run. On a given day or a given hour I'd like to know which jobs need to run. I have the following code to query my jobs table:

```
$job = Model_Job::find('first',
 array(
  'where' => array(
   array('status_id', 1), // active
   array('due_date', today)
)))
```

The last array is just pseudo code of course. I came up with the following code to figure out if a timestamp is today.

```
date('Ymd', strtotime(Date::forge(time())->get_timestamp())) == date('Ymd', strtotime($job->due_date))
```

How would I combine that with my query? Is there a better way then looping through the queried array?

Comment: can you not query using the db date?

Comment: the problem is, that the Unix Timestamp can be any time of a day, like 08:42:18, versus the day, which is a timespan.

Comment: You could check with your table date col < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(or equivalent) would work if it is the current day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now, this is probably not a good way but it was the first that came to mind.

$today = strtotime('today 00:00');

You can use the date from that snippet and set a `WHERE due_date > $today` I'm not quite sure how to do that with your database model.

edit: This relies on that you have correct timezone settings in your php configuration.

As sebastian pointed out, this will get all future dates also, but you could simply use the same technique to get the last timestamp of the day

```
$todaystart = strtotime('today 00:00'));
$todayend = strtotime('today 23:59:59'));
```

and the use a `BETWEEN` operator in your SQL-query

Comment: That would not work because it would get all future due dates.

Comment: ah, of course, but that would be simple enough to get the last timestamp of the day using the same technique and then using a `BETWEEN` operator instead.

Comment: `strtotime()` returns a unix timestamp, there's no need to use `date()` again.

Comment: Hah! My mind works in mysterious ways some times. You are correct, silly me.

Comment: Thanks that obviously works … I just thought there was a cleaner approach to it. (your approach is certainly better then mine)